# How to debug the error in this SQL command?

Tags: sql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to execute this SQL command to create a table.

```
CRETE TABLE NEWS (
  ID INT(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TITLE VARCHAR(128),NOT NULL,
  SLUG VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  TEXTS_S TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY (ID), );
)
```

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: @Armenak: that was not a good edit, since you changed the code that was presented. You added a full stop in the `CRETE TABLE NEWS` which the original poster did not intend, and fixed a spelling, and as a result answers are incorrectly responding to code the author does not have. Please be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
Create table news (   
    ID INT(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    TITLE VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,   
    SLUG VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,   
    TEXTS_S TEXT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

Missing `KEY` at the end, bogus comma on the line creating `TITLE`, another bogus comma on the `PRIMARY` line. First problem was the full stop in the table name.

Comment: The `Create table news` did not have a full stop in the code originally, a new editor incorrectly put that in. It was actually `CRETE TABLE NEWS` without the full stop. I have reverted that edit back to the original. I expect the question will close though, just letting you/OP know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table news
(
  ID INT identity (1,1)    primary key ,
  TITLE VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  SLUG VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  TEXTS_S TEXT NOT NULL  
)
```

Comment: We tend to discourage code-only answers here. It is much better to (also) add an explanation of what the problem was, and what you have changed. That said, this question is likely to close as "typographical error", so it is up to you whether you wish to improve it.